# switching ViewController in AppDelegate - doesn´t show up

Tags: objective-c, view, delegates, viewcontroller

stuck at this, seeking advice.

What i did and my Project:
i make a book for children. Every page is a custom ViewController. On every Page i have a button for next and previous Page. 
I use the AppDelegate to load the ViewControllers.
My AppDelgate starts with the ViewController1 and when i Press the Button/swipe in ViewController1 it should Load the ViewController2 but nothing happens.

My Code in AppDelegate:

```
self.view1 = [ViewController1 alloc];
[window addSubview:view1.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

- (void)goToNextPage {
    view2 = [ViewController2 alloc];    
    UIView *current = self.window;
    [self.window addSubview:view2.view];

    CATransition *animationT = [CATransition animation];
    [animationT setDuration:0.5];
    [animationT setType:kCATransitionMoveIn];
    [animationT setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
    [animationT setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    [[current layer] addAnimation:animationT forKey:@"SwitchToView1"];

 NSLog(@"works2");
}
```

Here my **ViewController1**:

```
- (void)addButtonNext { 
     UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector       (buttonClicked:)] autorelease];
    swipeGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    swipeGesture.direction = (UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft);
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture];
    NSLog(@"works0");
}


- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"works1");
    AppDelegate* next = [AppDelegate alloc];
    [next goToNextPage];
}
```

My Console says `works0 works1 works2`.
Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should take a look in the allocation/initialisation chapter in Apple's Objective-C guide first. It seems, like you haven't understood well these very fundamental concepts. You always never call alloc without a related init method.

Comment: with solution of farajnew it works. thanks for you time. i will read it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont allocate the application delegate
you need to deal with it like this

```
AppDelegate *next =(AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[next goToNextPage];
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you didn't **initialized** the second view controller :

```
view2 = [ViewController2 alloc];
```

Comment: @tomk, totally true, but I realize that andmany others after reading the code more deeply and now I believe his problem can be anywhere..